# Twill alternative for integration testing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, integration-testing, tipfy, twill

I am using to twill to do integration testing for an AppEngine (using tipfy micro framework) application but unfortunately twill is not maintained and I cannot test PUT and DELETE requests.
Is there any similar solution?

I am thinking of using PhantomJS, there are some python bindings and it can execute JS (as it is a headless webkit but I have not found much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not many alternatives for headless JS testing, you could try selenium 2 web driver. Good luck :)

Comment: That's what I am thinking for JS testing. Any suggestions for python integration testing?